# Regex to identify more than 1 occurance of underscore consequtively

Tags: java, regex

I have string in which more than one underscore can be present together.

For example : this_is__Dummy_____String

I have to replace this more than one occurance by only one underscore so that target string should look like :

this_is_Dummy_String

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `str = str.replaceAll("_{2,}", "_");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use String#replaceAll to replace the undescores.

```
"this_is__Dummy_____String".replaceAll("_{2,}", "_")
```

The given regex will replace all occurences of "two or more" underscores with a single underscore.